# vertical centering of text with variable font-size

Tags: html, css

I want to center text vertically in p element with flexible height(it can be multiline and have a variable font-size). So I give the same top and bottom padding:

```
padding: 4px 0;
```

But with bigger font-size it moves a little down so I have to set bigger padding-bottom:

```
.big{
    font-size: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 14px; 
}
```

How to make it centers vertical for both cases?
http://jsfiddle.net/uVsLn/1/

Comment: yes of course you can use % or em. -> padding: 0.4em 0;

Comment: Actually, both text are vertically centered by default. Just try using letters in uppercase and you will see that. When you use lowercase letters like g,y,p,q, it seems like that. Also when you use lowercase letters such as a,c,e,i,r,s,x,z, m v,u,m,n,o, it still feels the same as they don't extend like b,h,f,d,k,l,t. For the solution, you have to give padding-bottom manually like you had shown us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DhirajShah mentions in the comments under OP's question, both texts are actually vertically centered by default, it's just that browsers don't seem to take [descenders (the bottom part of the g which extends to under the baseline)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender)  into account when rendering vertically centered text, which results in the word *'big'* looking off-center [in your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/uVsLn/7/) with the added padding removed.

To prove this point you should have a look at [this version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/uVsLn/5/), all I have done is remove the extra padding on the bigger sized paragraph, and changed the word *'small'* to *'big'*. Now the small version of the word *'big'* doesn't look vertically centered either.

It's up to you to choose if you want the text vertically centered *including* or *excluding* the descenders.

If you choose to center it vertically ***excluding the descenders***, just remove all added padding at the bottom for all paragraphs and you're done, as this is the default behaviour. Now your text won't look vertically centered if it has descenders.

If you really want to have the text ***vertically centered including the descenders***, you're probably best off adding something like `padding-bottom: 0.1em;` to all paragraphs, this will add a little bit of extra padding under every paragraph. The `em` unit is the best choice here [as it ensures the size of the added padding varies based on the specified `font-size`](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm). The drawback in this approach is that now your text won't look vertically centered if it doesn't have descenders (e.g. when not using `g,y,p or q`, with `uppercase` set, or an when using an all caps font).

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/uVsLn/4/)</kbd> demonstrating the latter option.